# Formatting code in html from an sql database

Tags: php, html, sql, database, parsing

I am creating an application which stores text / code which the user inputs in an sql database, however when the code comes back out it is not formatted correctly. I would like it to be formatted to the standard formatting of the language or formatted the same way which the user entered it.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at htmlentities() [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp).